# DSE SOLR: Join solr cores on multiple fields

Tags: join, solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Given the following 2 tables in cassandra and all fields are indexed on SOLR

cqlsh> CREATE TABLE songs (song uuid PRIMARY KEY, title text, artist text, album text);

cqlsh> CREATE TABLE lyrics (song uuid, id uuid, words text, language: text, PRIMARY KEY (song, id));

Both tables share the song partition key, a uuid. The second table also contains the id clustering column.

Is it possible to filter based on multiple columns from the lyrics index ? I get a parse error.

For eg I want to select all the songs whose artist is michael and lyrics contain the word love and the language is english

select * from songs where solr_query='**artist:michael** AND {!join fromIndex=rfu.factor}**words:love AND language:english**';

I am not sure whats wrong with the above query ?

Comment: You could use the json syntax:
    `select * from songs where solr_query = '{"q":"{!join fromIndex=rfu.factor}words:love AND language:english", "fq":"artist:michael"}'`
But I am also curious to know how you could use the syntax above.

Comment: Thanks Mikael ... the json syntax works for me. However still I couldn't get the my original query syntax to work.